# Configure java objects construction without dependency injection

Tags: java

This is my code (just an example, of course):

```
Employee manager = new DefaultEmployee(/* dependencies */);
Budget budget = new DefaultBudget(/* dependencies */);
Project project = new DefaultProject(manager, budget);
```

`DefaultProject` depends on `Employee` and `Budget`, they depend on something else, etc., etc. Hierarchy of dependencies is rather big (may be hundred of types). I can hardcode (as in the example) or I can probably use some sort of configurations (XML or maybe YAML) and some builder which can create such hierarchy in runtime. Are there any solutions available, besides Spring Framework?

Don't offer dependency injection please.

This snippet has nothing to do with [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) design pattern, since consumers don't have any link to container. Moreover, there is no container at all (which is a static component of DI pattern, and is a brutal violation of OOP principles) and no [inversion of control](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html).

Comment: I will use dependency injection in such case. Just curious why you dont ?

Comment: Why not DI?  What you are doing is in fact Dependency Injection, in a hand-crafted manner.  Spring (or other DI framework like Guice) is doing exactly what you are asking for, it will be good if you can tell a bit on why you are saying no to DI.  (You are doing DI, and looking for a framework to do DI, but you don't want DI framework... :P that's sounds strange to me)

Comment: What you describe **is** (manual) dependency injection!

Comment: Dependency injection is a just pattern and the code you have shown follows that pattern. Why do you want to avoid a DI framework?

Comment: Dependency injection means static, which is against OOP. The code above has nothing to do with [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) since it doesn't have a container (which is a static evil).

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `ObjectFactory` which provides a method `<T> T getInstance(T Interface)`.

The factory then looks up an implementation for the Interface you have passed, instantiates and returns it. The `ObjectFactory` considers the constructors of the Objects it instantiates to lookup further implementations. This is pretty much reflection but works, I've already used this in a project.

In your example you will have to call

```
Project project = objectFactory.getInstance(Project.class);
```

The `ObjectFactory` finds the implementation (`DefaultProject`) and sees that the constructor needs an `Employee` and a `Budget`. So before instantiating the `DefaultProject` it looks up implementations for those (`DefaultEmployee` and `DefaultBudget`) and instantiates them. You have to use recursion here.

Comment: what if I have many implementations of the same interface in the same factory?

Comment: You should add a way to tell the ObjectFactory which implementations should be used for an interface. This can be done in specialized Factories like `DefaultObjectFactory` or `ExternalObjectFactory` which extends the `ObjectFactory`.

Comment: That's right, but I'm looking for an existing open source framework that can automate all this